# To have conditional ANDing inside WHERE clause

Tags: sybase

Can we add null check over one of the parameter of procedure inside WHERE clause and  avoid block of code getting repeated like

```
select aa=t1.aa,bb=t2.bb ,cc=t3.cc
 from t1,t2,t3,t4,t5
where t1.p1=t2.p1
and t2.p2=t3.p2
 IF(procParameter IS NOT NULL)
   and t3.p2=procParameter 
and t4.p2=t5.p2
and t5.p3=t1.p2
```

Look I want  one of the AND to get executed conditionally and otherwise it should NOT GET EXECUTED AT ALL..!!!!

How should I go for this optimisation?? 
I dont want code repeatation like

```
IF(procParameter IS NOT NULL)
begin
  select aa=t1.aa,bb=t2.bb ,cc=t3.cc
    from t1,t2,t3,t4,t5
     where t1.p1=t2.p1
    and t2.p2=t3.p2
    and t3.p2=procParameter 
     and t4.p2=t5.p2
    and t5.p3=t1.p2 
end
Else
begin
  select aa=t1.aa,bb=t2.bb ,cc=t3.cc
    from t1,t2,t3,t4,t5
     where t1.p1=t2.p1
    and t2.p2=t3.p2
     and t4.p2=t5.p2
    and t5.p3=t1.p2 
end
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach:

```
AND (procParameter IS NULL OR t3.p2=procParameter)
```